# Merge two methods into one

Tags: c#, oop

How can i merge methods below? and should i actually do this?

```
public IQueryable<ItemDTO> RepGetMonthItems(string inOut, string planFact, int month)
{
    return GetItemsWithCategory().
            Where(i => i.InOut.Equals(inOut)).
            Where(i => i.PlanFact.Equals(planFact)).
            Where(i => i.DateTime.Month.Equals(month));
}

public IQueryable<ItemDTO> RepGetYearItems(string inOut, string planFact, int year)
{
    return GetItemsWithCategory().
            Where(i => i.InOut.Equals(inOut)).
            Where(i => i.PlanFact.Equals(planFact)).
            Where(i => i.DateTime.Year.Equals(year));
}
```

Comment: Hopefully the various answers have shown you that they can be merged into one, but you end up with harder to read code and you'll have one method that does two things. So stick with what you have.

Comment: I disagree. You can do much better without breaking the 'do one thing' rule. Keeping it the way it is now just violates DRY instead.

Comment: @Baldrick, DRY needs to be applied with care as not repeating yourself leads to coupling. This is an example of where it's better to repeat yourself to keep things simple, though see my comment to your answer.

Comment: @DavidArno: By splitting the code into the main query, and then ways of subquerying, you and neither repeating yourself, nor are you having code that does 2 things. This is exactly with LINQ does - provide you with a box of flexible methods so you can build the query you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the 'do one thing' principle. But I also believe in DRY.

So.. extension methods to the rescue!

Have the main function do one thing (get report items) and extension methods filter by year or month.

Declare an extension method class like this:

```
    public static class QueryExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<ItemDTO> ForYear(this IQueryable<ItemDTO> query, int year)
        {
            return query.Where(i => i.DateTime.Year.Equals(year));
        }

        public static IQueryable<ItemDTO> ForMonth(this IQueryable<ItemDTO> query, int month)
        {
            return query.Where(i => i.DateTime.Month.Equals(month));
        }
    }
```

The create a cut-down `RepGetItems` method like this:

```
    public IQueryable<ItemDTO> RepGetItems(string inOut, string planFact)
    {
        return GetItemsWithCategory().
            Where(i => i.InOut.Equals(inOut)).
            Where(i => i.PlanFact.Equals(planFact));
    }
```

Usage then looks like this:

```
 var yearResults = originalQuery.RepGetItems(input, fact).ForYear(2015);
 var monthResults = originalQuery.RepGetItems(input, fact).ForMonth(10);
```

or even:

```
 var yearMonthResults = originalQuery.RepGetItems(input, fact).ForYear(2015).ForMonth(10);
```

Total flexibility, no loss of 'single purpose' principle.

Comment: Great idea, but only for "behind the scenes". Shove all this code into privates  and it'll nicely handle a growing number of public methods. But it's bad as a publicly-accessible solution as it's guilty of a diffusion of responsibility.

Comment: to be honest i totally prefer this

Comment: @DavidArno: Whether it's good for the OP's exactly case is hard to tell without the context of the code - it's more a demonstration that you can get a flexible solution without repeating yourself in this case. What's public / private / wrapped / exposed is another matter, and depends on more info than the OP provided :)

Answer (score 3):

No, you shouldn't. The three answers I see all break the "do one thing" rule by Robert "Uncle Bob" Martin. Read about it [here](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop).

Comment: and if I want to have a method that uses both year and month, I should write another one: public IQueryable<ItemDTO> RepGetMonthAndYearItems(string inOut, string planFact, int year, int month)?

Comment: @sterswift if that method always uses both parameters, yes.

Comment: Have to agree with the principle you give, but disagree that the code should be left as is. You can have the best of both worlds using extension methods. Otherwise you're just violating DRY instead.

Comment: @Baldrick could you help me to improve it, please?

Comment: @sterswift: See my answer below, using extensions methods.

Comment: @TimHausherr: Now add filtering by day, then month and day, then day and year, then day month AND year... how many methods will you need to have with all that repeated code? With extension methods, you can simply chain together whatever filters you like with no repeated code and no loss of 'single purpose' principle.

Comment: That is really getting complex IMHO. (And I believe in DRY too)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use `Nullable<int>` for year and month:

```
public IQueryable<ItemDTO> RepGetItems(string inOut, string planFact, int? year, int? month)
{
    return GetItemsWithCategory().
        Where(i => i.InOut.Equals(inOut)).
        Where(i => i.PlanFact.Equals(planFact)).
        Where(i => !year.HasValue  || i.DateTime.Year.Equals(year.Value)).
        Where(i => !month.HasValue || i.DateTime.Month.Equals(month.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.Where` conditions can be easily added to a query.

```
public IQueryable<ItemDTO> RepGetYearItems(string inOut, string planFact, int monthyear, bool useMonth)
{
    var query = GetItemsWithCategory().
        Where(i => i.InOut.Equals(inOut)).
        Where(i => i.PlanFact.Equals(planFact));

    if (useMonth)
    {
        query = query.Where(i => i.DateTime.Month.Equals(monthyear));
    }
    else
    {
        query = query.Where(i => i.DateTime.Year.Equals(monthyear));
    }

    return query;
}
```

or using `int?`

```
public IQueryable<ItemDTO> RepGetYearItems(string inOut, string planFact, int? year, int? month)
{
    var query = GetItemsWithCategory().
        Where(i => i.InOut.Equals(inOut)).
        Where(i => i.PlanFact.Equals(planFact));

    if (year != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(i => i.DateTime.Year.Equals(year.Value));
    }

    if (month != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(i => i.DateTime.Month.Equals(month.Value));
    }

    return query;
}
```

Note that this version is different from the one of @TimSchmelter... It isn't fixed (it depends on the "type" of SQL) what happens if you have in a query some "dead code" (pieces of query that aren't "active" because some parameters have a certain value, like int his query). His query clearly contains some "dead code" (the whole `i => !year.HasValue  || i.DateTime.Year.Equals(year.Value)`). If possible I prefer to omit it.

Comment: thanks for idea. but maybe more elegant solution exists?

Comment: `query = useMonth ? query.Where(i => i.DateTime.Month.Equals(monthyear)) : query.Where(i => i.DateTime.Year.Equals(monthyear))`

Answer (score 0):

How about using optional parameter here:

```
public IQueryable<ItemDTO> RepGetMonthItems(string inOut, string planFact, int month, int year = -1)
    {
        return GetItemsWithCategory().Where(i => i.InOut.Equals(inOut) 
          && i.PlanFact.Equals(planFact)) && year == -1? 
            i.DateTime.Month.Equals(month) : i.DateTime.Year.Equals(year));
    }
```

Take a look at this example :

[image]

As you can see each time you call method Where() you make a lot of extra work.

Comment: thanks for example of this construction inside where clause, didn't know it

Comment: btw you don't need that .Where.Where.Where